# Solving a maze using depth first search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, depth-first-search, maze

So I have this school project:
I am given as input a maze and I have to solve it. I thought of using the DFS algorithm to do so.

What I have done so far is transform my maze into a graph, in which the vertices are the non-wall positions of the maze.

I found some pseudocode for DFS online. I implemented it, but I don't understand how I am supposed to get a path out of it. The pseudocode of the algorithm is :

```
   dfs(graph G,vertex a)
   {
      ColorNode(a);
      for all vertices e adjacent to a
      {
        if e is endpoint
         END
        if e is not colored
         dfs(G, e)
      }  
    }
```

With this algorithm, all the nodes end up being colored..
If someone could give me a hand here, it would be really nice!

Answer (score 3):

The path is composed of the nodes in the stack trace. You can modify dfs to return a bool saying if it found the end, and when it returns true you would print or add to a list vertex `a` (note that this gives the path backwards).

Alternatively have a stack (global, or pass a reference to it in your function). When you call dfs push vertex a to it and pop it when you get back. Then when you get to the endpoint the stack contains the path.

All the reachable nodes should get colored unless END stop the entire program. I suspect you wrote it such that you keep going after you found the destination so your program keeps coloring nodes. There's no nice way to end a recursion (you can throw an exception, but that's just bad style) so you need to let the callers know that a solution is found and stop trying other things (you can return a bool if the solution is found, so when a call returns true you can immediatly return true).

Comment: I dont want to post a new answer because yours is imo the correct one. @Henry  in addition take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaBEKo5sM7w and skipt to 3:00 see that stack on the right side, it is exactly the path he went throuh to get to Node F ... Just for visualisation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was indeed letting the algorithm run after it colored the end node

Answer (score 1):

If all the nodes end up colored, it must have been some mistake in graph construction or in the maze design, since with this code sooner or later you should find an exit.

About finding back the path, you could do this: when you open a new node, pass to that node a reference to the node you came from, and store it inside the node: when you reach endpoint, just move back following the pointers you stored and you can rebuild the path that brought you there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with these kind of "how do I do DFS?" questions is that there is very little understanding of what is really happening.

Once you ask yourself *How would I travel the maze to find it's exit?* it is (well... should be) more or less straightforward, what to do:

You would knot a thread to your starting location, and then start wondering around, following these simple rules:

1. Whenever you arrive to a junction, you check if there is still some place where *you haven't been before*, and if there is, then you simply proceed in that direction.
2. If you arrive to a junction, from which it is no longer possible to progress any further, you mark that location as being *visited* by crossing two branches on the floor of the maze. Next time you will skip this junction, and you *go back from where you came from*.

In terms of your code fragment:

```
    dfs(graph G,vertex a)//What should I do at this junction?
   {
      ColorNode(a);//Stretch your thread to that junction
      for all vertices e adjacent to a//Choose a direction you haven't visited yet
      {
        if e is endpoint//If I found the exit of the maze
         END//I survived
        if e is not colored//If I haven't been in this direction earlier
         dfs(G, e)//Let's move on to that direction
      }  
    }
```